# How many distinct graphs with 10 vertices, each of which having an even degree, can be constructed?

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose `G=(V,E)` is a simple undirected graph, whose vertices are labelled 1,2,...,10 and degree of each vertex in `V`is even. How many such distinct (labelled) graphs with 10 vertices can be constructed?
How to approach this question?

Comment: Start with graphs with small number of vertices. What about $n=1, n=2,$ and so on? Can you do that?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a very difficult problem, but it is fairly instructive for a beginner in Graph Theory, especially when broaching the topic of vertex degrees and counting. Recall that there're exactly $2^{n \choose 2}$ labelled graphs on n vertices (to see this, note that there're ${n \choose 2}$ pairs of vertices in an n-vertex graph, and since there're 2 possibilities for each pair (either an edge is present, or it isn't), we get the desired count). Using this, we see that there are exactly $2^{9 \choose 2}$ = $2^{36}$ labelled graphs on 9 vertices. We claim now that there are the same number of labelled graphs on 10 vertices in which every vertex has even degree: For this, it suffices to establish a bijection between our two collections. Let G be a labelled graph on 9 vertices, and let G' be the graph obtained from G by adding the vertex x which is adjacent to every vertex of G which has odd degree. Since G must have an even number of vertices with odd degree (by the Handshaking lemma), x has even degree; moreover, each of the 9 vertices of G' which were from G also clearly have even degree by construction. Hence G' is a unique member of our collection of labelled graphs on 10 vertices corresponding to G (to make uniqueness more precise, you could show our operation has a well-defined inverse, though this is fairly obvious again by construction). This completes the problem.

**Remark:** Try to generalize your problem for arbitrary n!